# CentOS 7 ntpd not synchronize with AD domain controller

Tags: centos7, ntpd

i've a problem with time syncronization of a CentOS 7 host with a Windows 2008 R2 Domain controller.
If I use the command  `ntpdate -u host.domain` 
the synchronization is ok.
But using ntpd the time is always the same, here the result of the command ntpq -p:

```
 10.10.10.221    .LOCL.           1 u   65   64  377    1.740  965414.   4.054
 10.10.10.220    10.10.10.221     2 u   62   64  377    1.912  965408.  12.899
```

and the ntp.conf is the following:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
server 10.10.10.221 iburst prefer
server 10.10.10.220 iburst
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
disable monitor
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution after digging in more to a very similar issue on my end (different OS but same problem).

Windows NTP Servers (at times for various reaons), will report a large root dispersion. This in turn causes chronyd/ntpd to ignore the ntp server fpr inaccurate data.

In order to resolve I needed to add:

```
tos maxdist 16
```

to my /etc/ntp.conf. After restarting the service everything began working.

This article helped gave a simple explanation.

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4652771

I also stumbled upon this post regarding inadequate times which further helped troubleshoot and identify the issue.

[Why is NTP considering my server inadequate?](https://serverfault.com/questions/886954/why-is-ntp-considering-my-server-inadequate)

Answer (score 0):

Centos 7 use `systemd`. I suggest you use it.

Use the command [`timedatectl`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html)

Enable network time synchronization:

```
timedatectl set-ntp True
```

Create a conf file:

```
vi /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf
```

with content like this:

[Time]
   NTP= yourserver.org

Start `systemd-timedated` service:

```
systemctl start systemd-timedated
```

Comment: Umm, I don't believe `centos` chose to include `systemd-timesyncd` and so manufacturing a `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` would have no effect. I'm willing to be corrected but `systemd-timedated` does not read this file. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/312716/80414